# How to suspend and resume processes

Tags: bash, command-line, job-control

In the bash terminal I can hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend any running process... then I can type `fg` to resume the process.

Is it possible to suspend a process if I only have it's PID? And if so, what command should I use?

I'm looking for something like:

```
suspend-process $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

and then to resume it with

```
resume-process $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

Answer (score 248, accepted):

You can use `kill` to stop the process.

For a 'polite' stop to the process (prefer this for normal use), send `SIGTSTP`:

```
kill -TSTP [pid]
```

For a 'hard' stop, send `SIGSTOP`:

```
kill -STOP [pid]
```

Note that if the process you are trying to stop by PID is in your shell's job table, it may remain visible there, but terminated, until the process is `fg`'d again.

To resume execution of the process, sent `SIGCONT`:

```
kill -CONT [pid]
```

Comment: Unless there are other reasons for it, I would prefer SIGTSTP over SIGSTOP, as some applications do handle SIGTSTP specially.  For example, if scp is showing a progress bar, SIGTSTP will cause it to clean up the terminal mode before suspending, but if you send SIGSTOP, it will not have a chance to do so.

Comment: @ephemient I tried SIGTSTP, I saw what you were saying about it cleaning up the terminal. Thanks for the explanation of SIGTSTP, alawys good to learn new things :)

Comment: Also useful to note that you can reference the [pid] value by using the % symbol and then the job number (one that you can find by running `jobs`). So you'd go: `kill -TSTP %1`

Comment: See also: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886812/whats-the-difference-between-sigstop-and-sigtstp#11888074]

Comment: Why do you mean by *it may remain visible there, **but terminated*** ? It's not terminated but stopped/paused. I tried `kill -STOP` and it behaves exactly like `kill -TSTP` for shell jobs.

Answer (score 71):

You should use the `kill` command for that.

To be more verbose - you have to specify [the right signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP), i.e.

```
$ kill -TSTP $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

for suspending the process and

```
$ kill -CONT $PID_OF_PROCESS
```

for resuming it. Documented at [24.2.5 Job Control Signals](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Signals.html).

Comment: I wonder what accident of history led to this answer getting fewer votes?  The answers are nearly the same and this one came first....

Comment: @Wildcard, when I created the answer I was a bit in a hurry, thus, it basically just contained the first part up to `kill -TSTP` (i.e. how to suspend). 1/2 year later, i.e. 2011, I revisited my answer and noticed its incompleteness. Thus, I edited it and added also the `kill -CONT` part. This should explain the difference in votes in comparison with Steve's answer.