# How to suspend and resume processes like bash does

Tags: process, job-control, signals

this question is a follow-up to: [How to suspend and resume processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes)

I have started firefox from a bash session in gnome-terminal.

The process tree looks like this:

```
$ ps -e -o pid,ppid,cmd -H
 1828     1   gnome-terminal
26677  1828     bash
27980 26677       /bin/sh /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.15/firefox
27985 27980         /bin/sh /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.15/run-mozilla.sh /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.15/firefox-bin
27989 27985           /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.15/firefox-bin
28012 27989             /usr/lib/firefox-3.6.15/plugin-container /usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin/libflashplayer.so 27989 plugin true
```

When I hit `CTRL+Z` in bash, it will suspend firefox. When I issue the command `bg` (or `fg`) it will resume firefox. This is as expected.

When I issue the command `kill -s SIGTSTP 27980` in another terminal, it will print the line `[1]+  Stopped                 firefox` in the first terminal (just like when i hit `CTRL+Z`), but it does not suspend firefox. I asume it only suspends the shell script.

When I issue the command `kill -s SIGTSTP 27989` (note the PID) in another terminal, it will suspend firefox. The first terminal does not take note of this.

How does bash suspend the entire process tree? does it just traverse the tree and SIGTSTP all of the children?

Comment: See also [Difference between process group and job?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9082/difference-between-process-group-and-job/9151#9151).

Comment: You should add `pgid` to your `ps` command to see the process groups @geekosaur is talking about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Shell jobs live in "process groups"; look at the `PGRP` column in extended `ps` output.  These are used both for job control and to determine who "owns" a terminal (real or pty).

POSIX (taken from System V) uses a negative process ID to indicate a process group, since the process group is identified by the first process in the group ("process group leader").  So you would use `ps` to determine the process group, then `kill -s TSTP "-$pgrp"`.  (Try `ps -u"$USER" -opid,ppid,pgrp,cmd`.)

In your process tree, the process group starts with the `firefox` script launched by `bash`, so the process group would be 27980 and the command would be `kill -s TSTP -27980`.

Naturally, to resume the process group, issue `kill -s CONT -- -27980`.

Comment: By the way, `bash` isn't doing the `SIGTSTP` when you type `^Z`; since `firefox`'s process group is the terminal's current process group, the terminal driver (pedantically, line discipline) sends the `SIGTSTP` to all the processes in that process group.  `bash` is just `waitpid()`ing on it (and any other jobs).  Other terminal signals, such as `^C` and `^\ ` work the same way.  (meta:  SE hates that ctrl-backslash..)