# Send process to background using PID

Tags: kill, background-process

From [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2107/how-to-suspend-and-resume-processes) question I know you can resume a stopped process by doing

```
kill -CONT $PID
```

is there a kill option to resume a process but in the background (like `bg` but using a PID?)

Answer (score 1):

Sending `kill -CONT $PID` will not change the foreground/background status of the process indicted by `$PID`.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Implementation) says:

> A stopped job can be resumed as a background job with the bg builtin, or as the foreground job with fg. In either case, the shell redirects I/O appropriately, and sends the SIGCONT signal to the process, which causes the operating system to resume its execution.

Thus, since the shell I/O redirection will not change when using `kill -CONT $PID`, the process will effectively remain in the background of the shell.

Comment: @three-diag Since I can't comment above: this answers the question you ask in the body, but not in the title. Are you actually asking about programmatically causing the process to go to the background using its PID? Please update title/question to reflect the intended question.